# System.Service.ServiceActivation exception on SVC deployed in ISAPI folder

Tags: 2013, custom-field-types, isapi

I am using this [codeplex](https://sharepointlookup.codeplex.com/) code to develop advanced lookup. It mostly works fine till deployment. But when I tried to use it, on the list form it threw error in jquery file. Below is the error snapshot.[image]

Solution has two User Controls and one SVC service deployed in ISAPI folder.

Comment: Please Check if your search host controller service is working or not? If not then please do restart it from the Services.msc.

Comment: I verified and "SharePoint Search Host Controller" Service is running

Comment: Restart it and then try to deploy.

Comment: You mean. should i uninstall and install WSP again?

Comment: Restart the service. remove the solution from CA and install WSP

Comment: I did it. and it is still the same. One thing which i noticed is when i added -webapplication in the install command, it threw error saying "no resource scoped to web app". So i used Install-SPSolution –Identity MyAd.wsp  –GACDeployment

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50306/discussion-between-mohit-and-dikesh-gandhi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Robert's [blog](http://www.robertseso.com/2013/05/adding-custom-wcf-services-to.html), I realized that Visual studio was not replacing token for my SVC file.
So, i added below line of code in the .cproj file and it worked

```
<TokenReplacementFileExtensions>svc</TokenReplacementFileExtensions>
```